# jQuery UI Sortable. How to prevent from moving some specific item to the end of the list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of items that is powered with jQuery UI Sortable. I want to revert some specific item when I try to drag it to the end of the list. So it won't allow me to put this list item in the end of the list.
How to do this?